# Take average and ignore duplicate results in a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data similar to the following;

```
symbol   returns
LYS.PA   0.001470588
PWG.PA   0.11875
BALYO.PA 0.240875912
ADVIC.PA 0.000712758
ADVIC.PA 0.000712758
```

I am using the following formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(FREQUENCY(Q2:Q6;Q2:Q6);Q2:Q6))
```

I want to take the average and skip over the duplicated rows so `ADVIC.PA` would only be counted once.

This formula works but I want to use the `symbol` column as the duplicated rows not the `returns` column. I have issues when I have multiple firms with 0 returns, the above formula will ignore all these.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm assuming that you have data in range `A2:B6`.**

```
Unique Symbol         Value
LYS.PA            0.001470588
PWG.PA            0.11875
BALYO.PA          0.240875912
ADVIC.PA          0.000712758

Average:          0.090452315
```

***To get unique list of symbols*** write 
   this Array Formula in Cell `D2` finish 
   with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & Fill down.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $A$2:$A$6), 0)),"")}
```

*Formula in Cell `E2` & drag down:*

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A2:B6,2,FALSE)
```

*To get Average in Cell `E7` write this 
 Formula:*

```
=AVERAGE(E2:E5)
```

**Note:** *Adjust cell references in the 
           Formula as needed.*